# Building an alarm application in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, scheduled-tasks, nsnotificationcenter

I want to develop an alarm application in iOS. So far, I have created basic UI where the user can select the time when the alarm should trigger. The code schedules one local notification for this time using following code:

```
UNMutableNotificationContent *content = [UNMutableNotificationContent new];
    content.title = @"Helloooooo...";
    content.body = @"Time to wake up!";
    content.sound = [UNNotificationSound defaultSound];
    
    //create trigger
    UNCalendarNotificationTrigger *trigger = [UNCalendarNotificationTrigger triggerWithDateMatchingComponents:triggerDate repeats:NO];
    
    NSString *identifier = @"test";
    UNNotificationRequest *request = [UNNotificationRequest requestWithIdentifier:identifier
                                                                          content:content trigger:trigger];
    
    UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
    [center addNotificationRequest:request withCompletionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"Something went wrong: %@",error);
        }
    }];
```

Now, **when this notification is triggered, I want to play music (like an alarm tone)**. After lot of research I understood that there are no callbacks for the notification triggered event when the application is in background.

Another approach I tried in which the code tries to call the `playAlarmTone` method after certain timer:

```
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    
    //create new uiBackgroundTask
    __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];
    
    //and create new timer with async call:
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        //run function methodRunAfterBackground
        NSTimer* t = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:lroundf(secondsBetween)
                                         target:self
                                       selector:@selector(playAlarmTone)
                                       userInfo:nil
                                        repeats:NO];
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:t forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];
    });
```

But with this approach, the music is not playing if the alarm clock is set to more than 15 minutes from the current time.

What is a methods to run specific task after time interval of "x" minutes?

I found an [alarm application](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/alarmy-alarm-clock/id1163786766) on the App Store which can play alarm music for infinite time when alarm is triggered. How this app can determine when to start the alarm music?

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the music name by setting the `sound` property to your `content`.
So instead of:
`content.sound = [UNNotificationSound defaultSound];`

You should set:
`content.sound = [UNNotificationSound soundNamed:@"yourSoundName.mp3"];`

Also, make sure that your music length is not longer than 30 seconds.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I want the music to loop infinite time until the user performs specific action in the application.

Comment: What you want and what you can do often aren't the same.

Answer (score 0):

Did you already consider using NSTimer scheduledtimerwithtimeinterval? This could be used to perform an action after a time interval as per your need. Also, check this article http://andrewmarinov.com/building-an-alarm-app-on-ios/ from Andrew.

Comment: The idea here is to have the alarm sound even when the app isn't the foreground app, because an alarm app that has to be the foreground app all the time isn't so useful. Timers don't run when the app is in the background or not running at all, so local notifications are used instead.